# C++ Multiple Maps Inside Map

Tags: c++, dictionary, initialization, initialization-list

In python I can have a dictionary inside a dictionary like so:

```
dict = {  'a': { 1:1, 2:2, 3:3 }, 
          'b': { 1:1, 2:2, 3:3 }, 
          'c': { 1:1, 2:2, 3:3 }   }
```

In C++ I have to use a map inside another map:

```
std::map< std::string, std::map<int, int> > map1
```

But how do I achieve the same structure as the python example? Haven't been able to find any examples of this.

```
std::map< std::string, std::map<int, int, int> > ??

std::map<std::string, std::map<int, int>, std::map<int, int>, std::map<int, int> > ??
```

Comment: *"But how do I achieve the same structure as the python example?"* What's wrong with `std::map< std::string, std::map<int, int>>`?

Comment: It is fine, but how do I push multiple maps to it? Does it only work for 1?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat: I think he's wondering what the C++ syntax is for initializing a map object, since C++ doesn't do the `key:value` thing like Python and Javascript

Comment: Then they need to add that to their question

Comment: @OP: Try replacing all `:` with `,` and see what happens.  You may need an extra set of braces around each pair as well so that Python `key:value` becomes C++ `{key,value}`.  Nesting should still work.

Comment: what do you want to achieve with `std::map<int, int, int>` ? Would be good if you explain the python piece so that the question can be understood also by non-pythonians. Is `std::map< std::string, std::map<int, int> >` not already the same structure as the python map?

Comment: If I just use `map1['a']` am I able to insert `1:1, 2:2, 3:3`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you mean an initialization of the map object then it could look like

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <map>

int main() 
{
    std::map< std::string, std::map<int, int> > m =
    {
        { "a", { { 1, 1 }, { 2, 2 }, { 3, 3 } } },
        { "b", { { 1, 1 }, { 2, 2 }, { 3, 3 } } },
        { "c", { { 1, 1 }, { 2, 2 }, { 3, 3 } } },
    };

    for ( const auto &p1 : m )
    {
        std::cout << p1.first << ": ";
        for ( const auto &p2 : p1.second )
        {
            std::cout << "{ " << p2.first << ", " << p2.second << " } ";
        }
        std::cout << '\n';
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
a: { 1, 1 } { 2, 2 } { 3, 3 } 
b: { 1, 1 } { 2, 2 } { 3, 3 } 
c: { 1, 1 } { 2, 2 } { 3, 3 }
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Learned alot. Much appreciated! Will accept.

Comment: Just a final question. if I have a map that is  `{ {1,1}, {2,2}, {3,3} }` how would I insert it into map1?

Comment: Also note that `std::unordered_map` is closer to dictionary in Python.

Comment: @johnmondego There are several methods. For example you could do it like m["d"] = { { 1, 1 }, { 2, 2 }, { 3, 3 } };

Comment: @VladfromMoscow Alright thats what I thought. Thanks a lot! Have a good weekend sir.

Answer (score 1):

The syntax for placing keypairs into maps is different in C++ than it is in Python. In C++ the `std::map` container exposes the `emplace(key, value)` method in order to do something like `dict[key] = value`. It is also slightly different because C++ is strongly typed to you must provide the right type for the key and the value (as defined in the template)

To do the equivalent of your python code with `std::map` you would do this:

```cpp
std::map<std::string, std::map<int, int> dict
std::map<int, int> my_map;
my_map.emplace(1, 0); // Add a key of 1 with a value of 0 to the map
dict.emplace("My key", my_map); // Add the map to the other map with a key of "My map"
```

Comment: Perfect thank you! Great explanation. Upvoted Will accept the most upvoted question. Have a great weekend! Stay safe